# Viewpager with outside control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-view

I want to implement simple view pager with control from outside view.

Here is mockup:

[image]

view_with_pager.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:id="@+id/control_header"
        />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/control_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My purpose is to control view pager only with control_header. Maybe there is any simple way to implement this feature. Thanks

P.S. I added horizontal scroll bar just for example. It could be any view controlled with fingers like ViewPager.